# Pion pion collision

Tags: particle-physics, photons, momentum, conservation-laws, pair-production

I am following a course on subatomic physics and I was asked this question

> Consider the interaction $\gamma\to\pi^++\pi^-$. Which conservation law prohibits this reaction? And modify this reaction slightly such that it is possible.

I don't really know how to do this, in my opinion it is easy to conserve energy and momentum for this reaction and as far as I know, Isospin is conserved. So I was wondering, which conservation law is broken and what needs to be added to solve?

Comment: Easy? Did you outline this in your question?

Comment: What do you mean? Is either energy or momentum not conserved for this reaction?

Comment: Try to demonstrate and display relativistic conservation of Energy and momentum.

Comment: you should think about the inverse reaction. Can that one conserve momentum in the CM frame of the two pions?

Comment: For the reverse reaction, $\pi^+ + \pi^-\to\gamma$ ,Is it true that the momentum in the CM frame is zero, because that would mean there is no conservation of momentum since the photon can not have momentum 0

Comment: For all reactions, go to the center of mass . It is easy to see  then what is happening. left side? right side?  look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production#Photon_to_electron_and_positron . and it is a production proposal, not a collision for the pions

Answer (score 1):

This reaction needs two photons for it to be valid. Conservation of momentum is violated because something that is moving slows down. For conservation of momentum to not be violated you need two photons which would cancel out the momentums of the photons and result in  pi+ and pi- production.

$2\gamma\to\pi^++\pi^-$